# Sisyphus-rails is enabled but not working by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running Rails 4.2.5 with rvm.

I am hoping someone has experience with using the sisyphus-rails gem for browser side auto saving.

I am working on a large CMS focused rails application and I need browser side auto saving on many but not all admin forms. The app makes heavy use of simple_form and nested_form gems as well as custom form helpers. I have been testing the installation on a vanilla form_tag to be sure that the form_helper gems to not interfere.

I have sisyphus-rails installed as per the [documentation](https://github.com/dnoonan/sisyphus-rails), the sisyphus.yml is generated and sisyphus is required it in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.

Sisyphus is not being applied automatically to any form tags as the documentation says it should be (there is no `<script>...</script>` tags preceding the form tag in the browser)

`<script src="/assets/sisyphus….` IS being rendered the head.

Adding `:with_sisyphus=>true` to my form does not work.

In the rails console, calling `Sisyphus.config` returns `{"SISYPHUS_ENABLED"=>true}`.

Auto-save DOES work with `$(“#some-form-id").sisyphus();` in the individual template, but I need it to be available to almost all of the forms in the app through its aliased `form_tag` method.

**sisyphus.yml**

```
production:
  sisyphus_enabled: true

development:
  sisyphus_enabled: true

test:
  sisyphus_enabled: true
```

**Conclusion**

1. Looking for suggestions on how to debug or resolve this.
2. Will sisyphus-rails work with simple_form and/or nested_form?

Comment: I just scaffolded a single model rails app and sisyphus-rails aliase FormHelper methods do not work on this app either. Is this a rails version problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sisyphus-rails gem is no longer maintained and does not work with Rails 4.2 +